# Add String to an Array with Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

What I need to do is transfer Text from a text field into an array. here is what I am doing for getting the text:`NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@", textfield.text];`

Now how can I add this string to my array without loosing all of the objects already in the  array?

Comment: you should read apple documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of a NSArray.

You will find a very useful method

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
```

which

> Inserts a given object at the end of the array.

A simple use of NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *arMu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
NSString *s = @"Some string";
[arMy addObject:s];
```

Also if you have a @property define for the IBOutlet I would do this instead

```
NSString *string = self.textfield.text;
```

---

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) is always a good place to have answers

> writeToFile:atomically:
>       Writes the contents of the array to a file at a given path.
>       - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
>       **Parameters**
>       **path**
>       The path at which to write the contents of the array.
>       If path contains a tilde (~) character, you must expand it with stringByExpandingTildeInPath before invoking this method.
>       **flag**
>       If YES, the array is written to an auxiliary file, and then the auxiliary file is renamed to path. If NO, the array is written directly to path. The YES option guarantees that path, if it exists at all, won’t be corrupted even if the system should crash during writing.
>       **Return Value**
>       YES if the file is written successfully, otherwise NO.
>       **Discussion**
>       If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.
>       Availability
>       Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
>       See Also
>       – initWithContentsOfFile:
>       Declared In
>       NSArray.h

Comment: what would i put after the `-(void)addObject:(id)anObject`?

Comment: @DenaliCreative I'm not sure I understand your question but I've post a little sample code.

Comment: can i have the capacity be unlimited? also can i save the nsmutable array into a .plist?

Comment: @DenaliCreative you can save an NSArray to a file, and `initWithCapacity` the capacity is just a hint so the NSMuatableArray start with some size, but it will double in capacity every time it feels the need. There is a draw back on performance when that occur, so if you know you will need 10 000, you should init more than that.

Comment: How do I save the NSArray to a file? Like This: `NSUserDefaults *MyDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[MyDefaults setObject:arMu forKey:@"myFile"];`

Comment: @DenaliCreative that could be a way, but as with the other option, your Array have restriction on what it can contain to be able to save to a property list.